# Is the entire reducer step in hadoop map reduce thread safe?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

If I have member variable in the reducer class, and have the reduce function mutate the member variable, do I have to take extra caution to make it thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have member variable in the reducer class, and have the reduce function mutate the member variable, do I have to take extra caution to make it thread safe?

No, you don't have to take any extra caution - the member variable will be mutated inside the current `Reducer` but that would be isolated from any other instances of the same reducer class.